# Scipy in Cygwin

Tags: scipy, cygwin, python-3.8

I have been looking at all the previous posts in this forum related to the scipy installation in Cygwin. I have tried all the suggestions but without success.

Is there a kind of stablished solution?

Thank you in advance,

All the tips posted previously in the forum

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.